# List exported with item level permissions includes all records

Tags: permissions

I have a list of contacts that each department has permissions only to their own department items. It's managed through workflow, since many of the records were imported into SharePoint. When a user with permissions to only 5 items exports to Excel, all items are exported. Shouldn't the item level security be enforced when using Export to Excel. For now I've removed "Use clint integration features" from their permissions, but they would like to be able to export to Excel.

Bob

Answer (score 1):

It should only export the items user has permission to.

When you're running the Export to Excel, make sure Excel is actually running and logging on to SharePoint as the same user, and not logging in as some user with more permissions. Excel uses Internet Explorer Security settings to determine certain things regarding how it authenticates within domain and might in some scenarios automatically login using (in this case) *wrong* credentials.